# ggplot2, geom_bar, dodge, order of bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'd like to have ordered bars in dodge `geom_bar`. Do you know how to deal with it?

My code:

```
ttt <- data.frame(typ=rep(c("main", "boks", "cuk"), 2),
                  klaster=rep(c("1", "2"), 3),
                  ile=c(5, 4, 6, 1, 8, 7))

ggplot()+
    geom_bar(data=ttt, aes(x=klaster, y=ile, fill=typ),
             stat="identity", color="black", position="dodge")
```

And example plots to better understand the problem:

What I have:

[image]

What I would like to have:

[image]

Comment: Hello Marta, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One option would be to make a new variable to represent the order the bars should be within each group and and add this variable as the `group` argument in your plot.

Lots of ways to that task of making the variable, here's a way using function from *dplyr*.  The new variable is based on ranking `ile` in descending order within each `klaster` group.  If you have ties in any group you'll want to figure out what you want to do in that case (what order should the bars be in given ties?).  You may want to set the `ties.method` argument in `rank` away from the default, probably to `"first"` or `"random"`.

```
library(dplyr)
ttt = ttt %>% 
    group_by(klaster) %>% 
    mutate(position = rank(-ile))
ttt
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: klaster [2]

     typ klaster   ile  rank position
  (fctr)  (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)    (dbl)
1   main       1     5     3        3
2   boks       2     4     2        2
3    cuk       1     6     2        2
4   main       2     1     3        3
5   boks       1     8     1        1
6    cuk       2     7     1        1
```

Now just add `group = position` into your plot code.

```
ggplot() +
    geom_bar(data=ttt, aes(x=klaster, y=ile, fill=typ, group = position),
                     stat="identity", color="black", position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Generally it works - with one exception. When two bars have the same height. Like here: `ttt <- data.frame(typ=rep(c("main", "boks", "cuk"), 2), klaster=rep(c("1", "2"), 3), ile=c(5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 7))`. Do you know how to solve this situation?

Comment: @Marta Depends on bit on what order the bars should be in given a tie, but given that answer can set the `ties.method` argument in `rank` away from the default `"average"` to one of the other options.  See the `rank` help page for more info.