# ggplot barplot order according to max value for a row of two categories

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have searched around and found
[cases similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127081), but I cannot find a working solution to the following.

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
df <- data.frame(name = rep(c("a","b","c"), each=2), measure_type = rep(c("n1","n2"),3), value=c(20,1,3,3,17,9))


> df
    name measure_type value
  1    a           n1    20
  2    a           n2     1
  3    b           n1     3
  4    b           n2     3
  5    c           n1    17
  6    c           n2     9
```

I want to create a dodged bar plot with ggplot. X-axis should be name, y-axis should be value, `fill=measure_type` **and the dodged bars sorted according the highest value for measure_type=n1**.
The last feature (bold font) is what I am struggling with. I simply do not know how to produce it.

My code so far:

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = value, fill = measure_type)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())
```

Produces:

[image]

I want the smallest value of n1 determine the order of the dodged bar plots.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: to clarify, you would like your x-axis to be arranged:  B C A?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but my original data has far more than three "names" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort by `value` and then set the order of `name` to the sorted order of `name` for `measure_type=="n1"`. This can all be done on the fly using the `dplyr` pipe:

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(df %>% arrange(value) %>% 
         mutate(name=factor(name, levels=name[measure_type=="n1"])), 
       aes(x = name, y = value, fill = measure_type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())
```

[image]