# Sort grouped barplot by factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

here is a reproducible example of what i´m trying to do.

```
c <- structure(list(Observed = c(107, 62, 56, 63, 145, 72, 34, 79, 
107, 112, 45, 56, 72, 92, 158, 84, 129, 82, 140, 121, 99, 83, 
61, 69, 67, 58, 60, 75, 54, 56, 133, 70, 65, 150, 65, 97, 145, 
159, 90, 71, 80, 44, 145, 48, 112, 136), Treatday = c("Control_D0", 
"Treated_D0", "Treated_D0", "Control_D0", "Treated_D0", "Control_D0", 
"Treated_D0", "Control_D0", "Control_D0", "Control_D0", "Control_D0", 
"Treated_D0", "Control_D0", "Control_D0", "Treated_D0", "Control_D0", 
"Treated_D0", "Treated_D0", "Treated_D0", "Control_D0", "Control_D0", 
"Control_D0", "Treated_D0", "Treated_D0", "Treated_D0", "Control_D0", 
"Control_D0", "Control_D0", "Control_D0", "Treated_D0", "Treated_D0", 
"Treated_D0", "Control_D0", "Treated_D0", "Treated_D0", "Treated_D0", 
"Control_D0", "Control_D0", "Treated_D0", "Treated_D0", "Treated_D0", 
"Control_D0", "Treated_D0", "Control_D0", "Control_D0", "Treated_D0"
), Donor = structure(c(5L, 11L, 10L, 19L, 13L, 1L, 18L, 11L, 
2L, 9L, 7L, 17L, 8L, 4L, 14L, 10L, 23L, 1L, 16L, 12L, 21L, 15L, 
3L, 8L, 15L, 20L, 3L, 13L, 18L, 6L, 12L, 19L, 22L, 21L, 7L, 20L, 
14L, 23L, 4L, 9L, 22L, 6L, 5L, 17L, 16L, 2L), .Label = c("E", 
"I", "S", "P", "Y", "K", "J", "H", "Z", "U", "L", "A", "F", "M", 
"B", "G", "T", "N", "C", "X", "Q", "V", "D"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Observed", 
"Treatday", "Donor"), row.names = c("P31605L01001", "P31605L01002", 
"P31605L01010", "P31605L01012", "P31605L01013", "P31605L01016", 
"P31605L01022", "P31605L01032", "P31605L01033", "P31605L01038", 
"P31605L01039", "P31605L01041", "P31605L01042", "P31605L01043", 
"P31605L01044", "P31605L01045", "P31605L01050", "P31605L01052", 
"P31605L01053", "P31605L01056", "P31605L01065", "P31605L01066", 
"P31605L01067", "P31605L01073", "P31605L01080", "P31605L01088", 
"P31605L01091", "P31605L01093", "P31605L01101", "P31605L01105", 
"P31605L01106", "P31605L01111", "P31605L01112", "P31605L01121", 
"P31605L01122", "P31605L01123", "P31605L01129", "P31605L01130", 
"P31605L01136", "P31605L01138", "P31605L01140", "P31605L01146", 
"P31605L01164", "P31605L01165", "P31605L01168", "P31605L01169"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Then i generate the following graph

```
g<-  ggplot(c, aes(y=Observed, x=Donor,fill=Treatday)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(y="Value",x="Sample") 
print(g)
```

This will generate the following image.

How can I sort by treated_D0 from lowest to higher value ?

Thanks

[image]

The final desired results looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot barplot order according to max value for a row of two categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913183/ggplot-barplot-order-according-to-max-value-for-a-row-of-two-categories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
g <-  ggplot( c %>% arrange(Observed) %>%
    mutate(Donor=factor(Donor, levels=Donor[Treatday=="Treated_D0"])),
    aes(x = Donor, y = Observed, fill = Treatday)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())

print(g)
```

Comment: Works perfect. I have added the final desired plot to my post.