# Ordering grouped bars with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to visualize some data sorted by two variables: Year and Students. Here is my data:

```
graphos <- data.frame(c(2007,2007,2007,2008,2008,2008,2009,2009,2009),
                      c("A","B","C","A","E","B","D","B","A"),
                      c(52080,49426,42522,53124,50784,45920,55971,52216,49850))

names(graphos) <- c("Year","Classroom","Students")

graph2 <- ggplot(graphos, aes(fill=Classroom, y=Students, x=Year)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", color='black')

graph2
```

And here is the result:

[image]

I've tried the option of `fill=reorder`, but it doesn't work either:

```
graph2 <- ggplot(graphos, aes(fill=reorder(Classroom, -Students), y=Students, x=Year)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", color='black')

graph2
```

What I would need is to sort by both year (ascending) and students (descending), but my graph only order by year. Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Francesc, why do you keep rolling back the edits?

Comment: Hi. The suggest asks me to put an image directly, but I can't do it because I'm new...

Comment: Ah, don't worry about that. Let the mods approve the edits, instead.

Comment: Mmmm.... thanks... evidently, I'm new

Comment: This question is duplicated... [I finally found the answer!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127081/ggplot2-geom-bar-dodge-order-of-bars)