# Ordering grouped geom_bar left to right by height

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

The following R script:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.csv(text="x,value,version
foo,10,one
foo,12,two
bar,8,one
bar,7,two
baz,11,one
baz,14,two", header=TRUE)

png(filename="so.png")
ggplot(data,aes(data$x,data$value,fill=data$version)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") + 
  labs(x = "x",y="value") + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="version"))
dev.off()
```

Produces the following graph:

[image]

They appear left to right according to the "x" column (foo, bar, baz) alphabetically. However, I'd like the "x" column-grouped bars to appear according one of the versions, left most being the highest "value" column value. E.g. left to right according to values of "one" version. Thus:

- left most: baz (one:11,two:14)
- middle: foo (one:10,two:12)
- right most: bar (one:8,two:7)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5208679/324364)?

Comment: @joran I have. That answer does not consider grouped bar plots, as being asked here: grouped by "version", then ordered high to low according to one of those  "version"s.

Comment: The principle is always the same. Order the levels in the desired order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2, geom\_bar, dodge, order of bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127081/ggplot2-geom-bar-dodge-order-of-bars)

Comment: You don't need the `data$` part inside the `aes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general principle at the question I cited always holds: you control order by setting the factor level order. Many people get tripped up because the answer at that question doesn't always tell you in precise detail *how to reorder your factor in every single circumstance*. But the idea is always the same. Here are a variety of ways to approach setting the factor levels in that order:

```
#Cleverly
library(forcats)
data$x <- fct_reorder2(.f = data$x,
                       x = data$value,
                       y = data$version,
                       fun = function(x,y) x[y == "one"])

#Manually
data$x <- factor(data$x,levels = c("baz","foo","bar"))

#Tortuously
levels(data$x) <- data$x[data$version == "one"][order(data$value[data$version == "one"],decreasing = TRUE)]

#tidily
library(dplyr)
levels(data$x) <- data %>%
  filter(version == "one") %>%
  arrange(desc(value)) %>%
  pull(x)
```

Comment: Thanks! For the first option, `fct_reorder2`, I'm getting the error: `Error in check_factor(.f) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default
Calls: fct_reorder2 -> check_factor
Execution halted`

Comment: @RobStewart Looks like I have an old version of forcats installed where the first argument was `f` rather than `.f`. Sorry about that.