# ggplot separate a grouped bar plot into individual bars (in descending order by y-value)

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
# Create the dataset
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)
species = c(rep("sorgho", 3), rep("poacee", 3), rep("banana", 3), rep("tri", 3))
condition = rep(c("normal", "stress", "nitrogen"), 4)
value = abs(rnorm(12, 0, 15))
data = data.frame(species, condition, value)

#>    species condition       value
#> 1   sorgho    normal 18.94431427
#> 2   sorgho    stress  4.89350041
#> 3   sorgho  nitrogen 19.94698894
#> 4   poacee    normal 19.08643982
#> 5   poacee    stress  6.21962152
#> 6   poacee  nitrogen 23.09925063
#> 7   banana    normal 13.92850552
#> 8   banana    stress  4.42080670
#> 9   banana  nitrogen  0.08650759
#> 10     tri    normal 36.06980083
#> 11     tri    stress 11.45390192
#> 12     tri  nitrogen 11.98513873
```

With the dataset above I can create a grouped bar plot with this code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = reorder(species, -value), y = value, fill = condition)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

How can I make each individual bar showup on it's own in descending order, by y-value? It would resemble one long pareto chart. The `tri/normal` would be the first bar. The `poacee/nitrogen` would be the second bar, and so on. Here's what we're working with now.

[image: geombar]

I could achieve this by concatinating the species and condition into a new variable, and choosing that as my x-variable. I would prefer a simpler solution, perhaps some argument I can add to `geom_bar()`. I can't find a suitable argument when searching `?geom_bar()`. Is it possible?

[EDIT] - My question is not the same as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127081/ggplot2-geom-bar-dodge-order-of-bars). My question seeks to order all individual bars shown above, from first to last. The other SO question seeks to rank the bars only within each subgroup.

Comment: I think creating a new variable is the simplest solution by far. Otherwise you're trying to tell ggplot to treat the two variables as grouping variables, but then to ignore the grouping. I doubt that will be possible. You could still color the bars by condition.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. My motivation is I want the x-axis labels to be described with a single word, eg `tri` or `poacee` for each bar. Instead of `tri - nitrogen` or `poacee - nitrogen` etc. I could simplify things with stringr and `tri - n` or `poacee - n` but am hoping somebody has an answer that is more elegant.